# Expected Identifier Error when trying to run React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, es6-modules

I used to practice React on an online compiler named Codesandbox; And recently I tried going on a local environment (VS code). I have run my simple react code on it and it compiled well on browser BUT I can't get rid of this 'Identifier Expected' error on my console; It refuse to even let beautify does it's job :/

Here is the screenshot of my environment... I would appreciate it if someone can help me with it...

[Code and browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypKJy.png)

Comment: use no space like  <h1>hello</h1>

Comment: When I hit 'save' , it puts the spaces by itself and by deleting them nothing changed... still stuck . also Why my errors include typescript errors like... ts(17008) :/

Comment: so is a problem with your "format on save" maybe Prettier or something like, try to change  in bottom right of VSC BabelJavascript to Javascript

Comment: THANKS! I changed babel to javascript React... It worked...! ✋✋✋

Comment: Looks like you have not configured your local environment (IDE, compiler, linter, prettier, whatever) to support JSX syntax.